# scipy.optimize curve_fit returns wrong value (depends on the machine)

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I wrote some code with scipy.optimize curve_fit. It works perfectly on my computer:

Windows 7 Home Premium with Service Pack 1, 64bit
Dell Studio 1558
Intel Core i3 cpu M330@2.13GHz 2.13GHz, 3.86 GB of RAM
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:24:47)[MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
IPython 0.13.1

Then I moved the script to another machine (COMP2):
Microsoft Windows XP Professional Version 2002 Service Pack 3, AMD Athlon(tm) II X4 620
Processor 2.61 GHz, 3.25 GB of RAM, Physical Address Extension
Python 2.7.5 |32 bit | (default, Jun 14 2013,18:15:12) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
Ipython 1.0.dev

And the fits are really bad. My code was rather long but I prepared self containing example which reproduces all situation.

I read that sometimes helps when xdata and ydata are array( , dtype=float)  but this is not my case (I've tried)

I've even tried this code with Python 2.7.3 32bit on Windows 7 32bit ( my firends' machine) and it worked - so **I have no idea why fit results are so unpredictable and how I can force this code working properly on computer with COMP2.**

Here is self containing example:

```
from string import*
from numpy import *
from matplotlib.pylab import *
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from sys import exit

nm_range=[574.14200000000005, 574.154, 574.16499999999996, 574.17700000000002, 574.18799999999999, 574.19899999999996, 574.21100000000001, 574.22199999999998, 574.23400000000004, 574.245]
data_for_fit=[859.0, 997.0, 1699.0, 2604.0, 2013.0, 1964.0, 2435.0, 1550.0, 949.0, 841.0]
guess=[574.1861428571428, 574.2155714285715, 1302.0, 1302.0, 0.0035019999999983615, 859.0]

def f_double_gauss(x,x0,x1,A0,A1,sigma,c):
        return A0*exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2.*sigma**2)) + A1*exp(-(x-x1)**2/(2.*sigma**2)) + c

popt,pcov=curve_fit(f_double_gauss,nm_range,data_for_fit,guess,maxfev=10000)

print guess
print popt

fig=figure("If fit of gauss or double gauss is good")
ax=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
pdata,=plot(nm_range,data_for_fit,"bo-")
guessed=[]
for i in nm_range:
    guessed.append(f_double_gauss(i,guess[0],guess[1],guess[2],guess[3],guess[4],guess[5]))


pfit,=plot(nm_range,f_double_gauss(nm_range,popt[0],popt[1],popt[2],popt[3],popt[4],popt[5]),"k-")
pguess,=plot(nm_range,guessed,"y")
ax.set_title("Anizo fit"+" : data, init guess & fit")
ax.set_xlabel("wavelenght [nm]")
ax.set_ylabel("PL intensity")
legend([pdata,pguess,pfit],["data","guess","fit"])
show()
```

Output for bad fit:

```
[574.1861428571428,574.2155714285715,1302,1302.0,0.0035019999999983615,859.0]
[5.69174152e+02 8.66516577e+04  -9.27629569e+04 1.59887720e+09  7.56288801e-03  1.59110000e+03]
```

Output for good fit:

```
[574.1861428571428,574.2155714285715,1302,1302.0,0.0035019999999983615,859.0]
[ 5.74177150e+02    5.74209188e+02  1.74187044e+03  1.58646166e+03  1.0068462e-02   8.57450661e+02]
```

good fit image: 
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6GA05-W4ZzzdTIxa3U3Rl92MU0/edit?usp=sharing

bad fit image
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6GA05-W4ZzzRlk4eWlER01WejQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I've tried to run this script on Windows 7 32bit with Enthought canopy-1.0.3-win-32.msi and still doesn't work.

Comment: I reinstalled Python for:
python-2.7.5
numpy-MKL-1.7.1.win32-py2.7

scipy-0.12.0.win32-py2.7
matplotlib-1.2.1.win32-py2.7
Doesn't work :(

Comment: I reinstalled Python again on Windows 7 32 bit for:
python-2.7.5.amd64.msi
matplotlib-1.2.1.win-amd64-py2.7
numpy-MKL-1.7.1.win-amd64-py2.7
fit is still bad
scipy-0.12.0.win-amd64-py2.7

Comment: I've tried to multiply all data by factor 1e6 and 1e9 and 1e16 but fit is still bad.
I run this code on Mac, with anaconda 1.6.1 for 64 bit OS and fit fails. 
I am not sure about that but I think that there is something wrong with optimize.leastsq method

Comment: I installed Anaconda 1.6.2 64bit with 2.7.5 (AMD64) python on Windows 7 64bit machine with Intel Core i5-3470 and 16GB RAM , the fit is still bad.

Comment: Ok, fit converges with python 2.7.3 installed from EPD 7.3-2. And that was on 32bit machine. So conclusion is that it not depends on architecture of the system (fortunately).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, the problem is with optimize library attached to current scipy.

When I copied **_minpack.pyd** and **minpack.py** from files attached to EPD 7.3-2 and put instead of current **_minpack.pyd** and **minpack.py** files the fit is perfect.

I will report that bug to scipy.